# Execute an EXE file using SP Designer Workflow on Approve Button Click

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have a requirement wherein the end user fills up SharePoint UI and submits the form and it will trigger a SP Designer 2010 workflow and assign a task to approvers.

Now, once the the approvers' form is populated, they are able to see the form and they click on a approve button, here I need to execute an EXE that's stored on the D:\ drive [say file system].
How to execute this EXE from a SP Designer 2010 WF?

And if the approver clicks on the Reject button , the EXE must NOT be executed.
I have checked the `Actions` in SP D, but there is no action called execute an Exe. So am stuck with, how to achieve this functionality.

One alternative approach i have thougt about is, once the approval status is set to "Approved", I can add an item into a  separate `SPList` and once this item added event is fired, I can write a ItemAddedEventReceiver method in which, I use `System.Process` namespace and invoke the EXE.  but this seems to be a complex logic.

Would like to know any other easy approaches/solutions.

Comment: do you have a single server farm? or a multi server farm?

Comment: on the dev env,. i am having single server farm where hyper-v manager is configured with a VM - SP 2010+sql server 2008 r2 IS INSTALLED, But in my prod. i would be having a multi server - farm environment. Whats the significance of your question ? how does it affect , the workflow /  EXE ?

Comment: If you will run the exe in the same WFE server I think it won't be a problem, but I've some issues caused by the double hop problem in the past, trying to run services in the other App Servers in my farm. check this, maybe applies to you. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/knowledgecast/2007/01/31/the-double-hop-problem/

Comment: Thanks for your valuable information.I am looking into this.